# How to create a subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

how can i combine 2 mysql statement into one statement.

These are my statements

MYSQL 1

```
SELECT et.imei as IMEI, MAX(FROM_UNIXTIME(et.timestamp)) as TID
FROM exp_terminal_log as et
group by et.imei
order by TID desc;
```

MYSQL 1 OUTPUT

```
IMEI              LATEST DATE
351895053434419   2013-04-28 11:12:28
354851057203265   2013-04-28 11:10:44
354851057234989   2013-04-28 11:10:32
```

MYSQL 2

```
SELECT ct.title AS TITLE, t.phoneid as IMEI
FROM transactions AS t
inner JOIN exp_channel_titles AS ct ON (ct.entry_id = t.restaurant_id)
WHERE t.cardid != '88888888' AND t.cardid > 0
AND ct.status= 'open'
GROUP by ct.entry_id
```

MYSQL 2 OUTPUT

```
TITLE       IMEI
Café Katz   351895053434419
Restaurant1 354851057203265
Restaurant2 354851057234989
```

Desired output

```
TITLE       IMEI               LATEST DATE
Café Katz   351895053434419    2013-04-28 11:12:28
Restaurant1 354851057203265    2013-04-28 11:10:44
Restaurant2 354851057234989    2013-04-28 11:10:32
```

this is how tried, but this does not work, because of my subquery is returning more than one row.

```
SELECT et.imei as IMEI, MAX(FROM_UNIXTIME(et.timestamp)) as TID
FROM exp_terminal_log as et
group by et.imei
having et.imei = (

SELECT t.phoneid as IMEI
FROM transactions AS t
inner JOIN exp_channel_titles AS ct ON (ct.entry_id = t.restaurant_id)
WHERE t.cardid != '88888888' AND t.cardid > 0
AND ct.status= 'open'
GROUP by ct.entry_id )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  ct.title AS TITLE, 
  t.phoneid as IMEI,
  t2.TID
FROM transactions AS t
inner JOIN exp_channel_titles AS ct ON ct.entry_id = t.restaurant_id
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT et.imei as IMEI, MAX(FROM_UNIXTIME(et.timestamp)) as TID
  FROM exp_terminal_log as et
  group by et.imei
) AS t2 ON t.phoneid = t2.IMEI
WHERE t.cardid != '88888888' 
  AND t.cardid > 0
  AND ct.status= 'open'
GROUP by ct.entry_id;
```

Comment: Arrh thank you @Mahmoud Gamal :) I will accept you answer within 7 min :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a join of the two subqueries:

```
SELECT titles.TITLE, titles.IMEI, dates.TID  FROM 
   (SELECT et.imei as IMEI, MAX(FROM_UNIXTIME(et.timestamp)) as TID
       FROM exp_terminal_log as et
       group by et.imei
       order by TID desc) dates
  INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT ct.title AS TITLE, t.phoneid as IMEI
       FROM transactions AS t
       inner JOIN exp_channel_titles AS ct ON (ct.entry_id = t.restaurant_id)
       WHERE t.cardid != '88888888' AND t.cardid > 0
       AND ct.status= 'open'
       GROUP by ct.entry_id ) titles
  ON titles.IMEI=dates.IMEI
```